# Re-Binding Event-Handlers in ASP.NET 4.0 "Templated Control"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, user-controls

**Edit**:  Sadly, nobody seems to know.  Maybe this will help clarify my dilemma:  I'm trying to implement my own DataList type of control that supports switching from ItemTemplate to EditItemTemplate.  The problem occurs when clicking on a button inside the EditItemTemplate -- it doesn't trigger the handler unless you click a second time!

Sorry about the lengthy post.  The code is complete, but hopefully with nothing distracting.

I'm trying to create my own User Control that accepts multiple templates.  I'm partly following techniques 39 and 40 from "ASP.NET 4.0 in Practice" by Manning.  It seems to be working, except the button inside the template isn't bound to the handler until the second click (after one extra postback).

There are four files involved.  Default.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <%@ Register Src="~/TheTemplate.ascx" TagPrefix="TT" TagName="TheTemplate" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <div>
                            <TT:TheTemplate ID="tt" runat="server">
                                    <ATemplate>
                                            <p>This is template A</p>
                                            <asp:Button ID="TemplateAButton" OnClick="TemplateAButton_Click" runat="server" Text="Template A Button" />
                                    </ATemplate>
                                    <BTemplate>
                                            <p>This is template B</p>
                                            <asp:Button ID="TemplateBButton" OnClick="TemplateBButton_Click" runat="server" Text="Template B Button" />
                                    </BTemplate>
                            </TT:TheTemplate>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="ToggleTemplate" Text="Toggle Template" OnClick="ToggleTemplate_Click" runat="server" />
                    </div>
            </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
    using System;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    Trace.IsEnabled = true;
                    tt.DataBind();
            }


            protected void ToggleTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    tt.TemplateName = (tt.TemplateName == "A") ? "B" : "A";
                    tt.DataBind();
            }


            public void TemplateAButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    Trace.Write("TemplateAButton_Click");
            }


            public void TemplateBButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    Trace.Write("TemplateBButton_Click");
            }
    }
```

And the user control, TheTemplate.ascx:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TheTemplate.ascx.cs" Inherits="TheTemplate" %>

    <p>Using template <asp:Literal Text="<%# TemplateName %>" ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
    <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />
```

And finally, TheTemplate.ascx.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;

    [ParseChildren(true)]
    public class TheTemplateContainer : Control, INamingContainer
    {
            private TheTemplate parent;
            public TheTemplateContainer(TheTemplate parent)
            {
                    this.parent = parent;
            }
    }


    public partial class TheTemplate : System.Web.UI.UserControl, INamingContainer
    {
            public string TemplateName
            {
                    get { return (string)(ViewState["TemplateName"] ?? "A"); }
                    set { ViewState["TemplateName"] = value; }
            }


            [TemplateContainer(typeof(TheTemplateContainer))]
            [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
            public ITemplate ATemplate { get; set; }


            [TemplateContainer(typeof(TheTemplateContainer))]
            [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
            public ITemplate BTemplate { get; set; }


            protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
            {
                    TheTemplateContainer container = new TheTemplateContainer(this);
                    if (TemplateName == "A")
                            ATemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
                    else if (TemplateName == "B")
                            BTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);

                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);

                    EnsureChildControls();
                    base.OnDataBinding(e);
            }
    }
```

When you first run it, you will see ATemplate being used:

[image]

If you click on the Toggle Template button, all the text is correctly rendered:

[image]

But clicking on either "Template A Button" or "Template B Button" will not trigger the OnClick handler on the first try:

[image]

It will work on the second click:

[image]

Does the problem have to do with where .DataBind() is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand it, but the problem has to do with how newly-added controls go through the "catch-up" events.  Removing PlaceHolder1 and adding it programmatically solves the issue.  TheTemplate.ascx becomes:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TheTemplate.ascx.cs" Inherits="TheTemplate" %>

    <p>Using template
            <asp:Literal Text="<%# TemplateName %>" ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
```

... and in TheTemplate.ascx.cs, replace OnDataBinding like this:

```
protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
{
    TheTemplateContainer container = new TheTemplateContainer(this);
    if (TemplateName == "A")
        ATemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
    else if (TemplateName == "B")
        BTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);

    System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder();
    //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.Controls.Add(PlaceHolder1);

    EnsureChildControls();
    base.OnDataBinding(e);
}
```

In the future, if I ever feel like I need to add controls dynamically, I will also create a PlaceHolder dynamically and use that as the root.  When PlaceHolder is populated, I will then add it to the page.